# Android beacon library Background service - UI lag when Video Play or Load some API Data

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I'm developing a beacon application scanner (in Background when Bluetooth is activated) with [Android Beacon Library](http://www.example.com/). 
The problem is whenever I activate the scanner in as a background, and I try to play a video with MediaController in another Activity or to load some API data, the video is not playing or sometimes it plays with lagging and the same as the API loading action.

But when I disable the scanner all works fine.

I don't know if the library runs its services in another thread or the same thread that blocks the UI, so I want to know how can I resolve this problem with multitask solution if it is possible.

I used **huawei HOL-19 , API19**

this is the CustomApplication file:

```
import android.R
import android.app.*
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.*
import android.util.Log
import com.example.anymarketmobile.views.subactivities.HomeActivity
import org.altbeacon.beacon.*
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap

class BackgrounApplicationBeacons : Application(), BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier {
    //  Init Properties
    lateinit var mBeaconManager: BeaconManager
    var mRegion: Region? = null
    var mMonitor = false
    var mLastDetectedBeacon: Beacon? = null
    val TAG = "==>"

    //  Actions & Callbacks
    override fun onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        mBeaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this)
        try {
            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(mRegion!!)
        } catch (e: RemoteException) {
        }
    }

    override fun didRangeBeaconsInRegion(beacons: MutableCollection<Beacon>?, region: Region?) {
        Log.i("==>Beacons:", "${beacons?.size}")
        if (beacons?.size!! > 0) {
            val beacon = beacons.iterator().next()
            if (beacon.id1 != mLastDetectedBeacon?.id1) {
                Log.i("${TAG}beacon detected:", "${beacon.id1} , ${beacon.distance} m")
                mLastDetectedBeacon = beacon
            }
        }
    }

    //  Start monitoring beacons
    fun startMonitoring() {
        mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)
        Log.i("==>", "Application launched:")
        if (mBeaconManager.isMainProcess) {
            mBeaconManager.beaconParsers.clear()
            mBeaconManager.beaconParsers.add(
                BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(Constants.DEFAULT_BEACONS_LAYOUT)
            )
            mBeaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)
            val backgroundPowerSaver = BackgroundPowerSaver(this)
            mBeaconManager.backgroundBetweenScanPeriod = 0
            mBeaconManager.backgroundScanPeriod = 2100
            mRegion = Region("test", null, null, null)
            // mRegionBootstrap = RegionBootstrap(this, mRegion)
            mMonitor = true
            val builder = notificationBuilder()
            mBeaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 456)
            Log.i(TAG, "startMonitoring")
            mBeaconManager.applySettings()
            mBeaconManager.bind(this)

        }
    }

    //  Stop monitoring beacons
    fun stopMonitoring() {
        mRegion = null
        mBeaconManager.removeRangeNotifier(this)
        mBeaconManager.unbind(this)
        /*mRegionBootstrap?.disable()
        mRegionBootstrap = null*/
        Log.i(TAG, "stopMonitoring")
        mMonitor = false
        mLastDetectedBeacon = null
    }

    fun isMonitoring() = mMonitor


    //  Forground notification builder
    private fun notificationBuilder(): Notification.Builder {
        val builder = Notification.Builder(this)
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_search_category_default)
        builder.setContentTitle("Scanning for Beacons")
        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(Constants.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_COMMUNICATION_BEACON_SCAN, mMonitor)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                "My Notification Channel ID",
                "My Notification Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            channel.description = "My Notification Channel Description"
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
            ) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            builder.setChannelId(channel.id)
        }
        return builder
    }
}
```

I expected to avoid any lag or slowly execution.

Comment: Of you disable all your logic in didRangeBeaconsInRegion, do you still see the same lag issues?  Do you have a large number of beacons other BLE devices visible in the vicinity?

Comment: @davidgyoung hello Mr.David, first thank you for your answer.
when I disable all logic in didRangeBeaconsInRegion, the video and the api call works but **not fine**, I mean lagging still exist but with less time

Answer (score 2):

Much of the work of the Android bluetooth stack is on the UI thread -- all detection callbacks are made on the UI thread for example.  The Android Beacon Library maintains its own background thread pool and immediately switches detection processing to a lower-priority background thread once a packet comes in from the operating system.  As a result, the library processing overhead on the UI thread is minimal -- limited to just handing off work to a different thread for each packet seen.

However, the operating system portion of the BLE detection processing is a different story, and some of it is done on the UI thread.  I would be surprised if there were significant Android OS processing on the UI thread from a BLE scan unless a very large number of BLE devices were visible at the same time.   I have not specifically tested this on a Huawei HOL-19, but I have tested it on stock Android devices (e.g. Pixel and Nexus devices) and confirmed the UI processing is minimal in cases where a dozen or fewer BLE devices are visible.

You might try a different device to see if it might be a Huawei HOL-19 specific issue.

Comment: Now, I tested in another device: **Huawei LUA-L21 - v 5.1 API 22** , and I have the same issue as my first device .. 
so what should I do in this case? 
thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry , my to fix my fault: my phone is Huawei HOL-19 not UOL . thanks in advance sir .

Comment: hello Sir @davidgyoung, it still no fix for that ? :(

Comment: I do not know why beacon scanning stalls video playback on your Huawei devices.  I would suggest trying on a non Huawei device to see if it is a Huawei specific issue, or maybe look at using profiling tools on Android Studio.

Comment: thank you sir for your answer, now I tested the library with Samsung S5 , it worked like a charm ! 
so i think it is a problem relative to my phone.

Comment: Hello agin Sir,  I found a solution for my issue, I just implemented the interface **BootstrapNortifier** in my custom application class **BackgroundApplicationBeacons** , then I configured these lignes like this and moved it to onCreate():
      ``mBeaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)
        mBeaconManager.backgroundBetweenScanPeriod = 0
        mBeaconManager.foregroundBetweenScanPeriod = 0
        mBeaconManager.backgroundScanPeriod = 3500``
Now there is no lag in the App.